# How to concatenate several .mat files into one

Tags: matlab

I have several mat file like: first.mat ,second.mat ,third.mat,...

all of these files have the same content like: variable1<3400x1 double> , variable2<1143x1 double> , variable3<1141x1 double> , ...

all mat files have the same content but the size of each variable in each mat file is different. I need to concatenate all same variables in all mat files in order to have just one mat file.

can somebody tell me what can I do?which function should I use?

Many thanks.

Comment: What you want is quite specific, I doubt there is a built-in function to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "all same variables"? It seems from your example the variables are not the same. Can you please give a more clear example of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no matlab function to do this, you need to open all individual vectors, combine them in the way you want, and save them back to disk. Something like this (untested):

```
filenames = {'file1.mat', 'file2.mat', ...};

data = cell(length(filenames), 1); % cell array to store all vectors

for i = 1:length(filenames)
    var = load(filenames{i});
    data{i} = var; % store single vector into cell array
end
data = cell2mat(data); % combine all small column vectors into one big one
save('combined_vars.mat', data)
```

Comment: `var` will be a struct here so I'm not sure `cell2mat` will work. That's why I used `fieldnames` and `getfield` in my answer.

Comment: Then get the data out of the struct on every iteration, and store it in the cell array, the idea stays the same.

Comment: Correction - `save('combined_vars.mat', 'data')`. +1 Tested and it works!

Comment: Don't you need to vertically concatenate the data,  across `data(1,1).variable1`, `data(2,1).variable1`, `data(3,1).variable1`and so on?

Comment: I put all the column vectors into a column-shaped cell array, which is then concatenated after the loop using [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html). This is faster than growing an array by concatenating once per iteration, since that way you need to allocate more and more memory for a bigger vector on every iteration, this is quadratic behavior, which should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: As I said, you still have `data(1,1).variable1`, `data(2,1).variable1`, etc. for the mat files separately. Shouldn't it be data(1,1).variable1 holding data from all mat files?

Comment: I think the easiest is to get the data out of the struct before you put it into the cell array, something like `fnames = fieldnames(var); data{i} = var.(fnames{1});`. But the question is a bit vague about the exact content of the files ...

Comment: Yes agreed on that, the OP didn't mention how the "concatenation" be done. Does he/she require a bigger final column vector, then OP need to do `vertcat` on top of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers,here is the final code which is working correctly.

```
clear
PathName = uigetdir;
file_all = dir(fullfile(PathName,'*.mat'));
matfile = file_all([file_all.isdir] == 0); 
clear file_all PathName

x=[];                               % start w/ an empty array
for i=1:length(matfile)
    x=[x; load(matfile(i).name)];   % read/concatenate into x
end

b=[];
for j=1:length(x)
    b=[b; x(j, 1).variable1];
end

FileName = [matfile(i,1).name(1:end-9),'.mat'];
save(FileName,'matfile','x','b');
```